# ¿Cómo determinar el número de hojas con profundidad mayor a K en árboles binarios?

Tags: c++

tengo un problema con un ejercicio de árboles binarios en C++. Dado un número k no negativo, hay que hacer una función para averiguar cuántas hojas de un árbol dado tienen una profundidad mayor que ese número k.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La función tiene la forma de

```
unsigned int numero_hojas_mas_profundas_que(const Arbin<int>& a, unsigned int k) {}
```

Para este caso por ejemplo, si k=0, la función devuelve 3. Si k=2, devuelve 2... Etc.
Gracias de antemano.

De momento tengo esto:

```
    unsigned int numero_hojas_mas_profundas_que(const Arbin<int>& a, unsigned int k) {
    // A IMPLEMENTAR
    int h = 0;
    int r = 0;
    if (!a.esVacio()) { 
        if (a.hijoDer().esVacio() && a.hijoIz().esVacio()) { // es Hoja
            if (h > k)
                r += 1;
        }
        else {
            h += 1;
            numero_hojas_mas_profundas_que(a.hijoIz(), k);
            numero_hojas_mas_profundas_que(a.hijoDer(), k);                 
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Claro que, al ser recursivo, el valor de h y r se reemplaza todo el rato. Meter los valores como parámetro no es una opción tampoco.

Comment: Y que has probado? Deberías pasar por la sección [ask] y realizar el [tour]

Comment: Pues de momento estoy así (lo siento pero no sé cómo meterlo en un cuadro):

unsigned int numero_hojas_mas_profundas_que(const Arbin<int>& a, unsigned int k) {
 // A IMPLEMENTAR
 int h = 0;
 int r = 0;
 if (!a.esVacio()) { 
  if (a.hijoDer().esVacio() && a.hijoIz().esVacio()) { // es Hoja
   if (h > k)
    r += 1;
  }
  else {
   h += 1;
   numero_hojas_mas_profundas_que(a.hijoIz(), k);
   numero_hojas_mas_profundas_que(a.hijoDer(), k);     
  }
 }
 return r;
}

Comment: Puedes [edit] tu pregunta en lugar de añadir esta info en un comentario.

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo dividir ese problema en múltiples partes:

1. Función que se encarga de calcular la profundidad de un nodo, esta puede ser hallada contando cuántas veces puede "subir" el nodo, es decir, usar el padre.

   ```
    template <class t>
    size_t profundidad(typename Abin<t>::nodo n,Abin<t>&a){
       if (n==a.raizB())
         return 0;
       return 1+ ej3(a.padreB(n),a); 
     }
   ```
2. Función encargada de iterar todos y cada uno de los nodos del árbol, y contar cuántos nodos con la profundidad dada (p) existen.

> En mi caso el recorrido lo hago en inorden, pero valdría cualquiera.

```
     template<class T>
     void cuenta_nodos_prof(typename Abin<T>::nodo n, const int& p, int& n_nodos, 
     const Abin<T>& A){
       if(n != Abin<T>::NODO_NULO){
         cuenta_nodos_prof(A.hijoIzq(n), p, n_nodos, A);
         if(p == profundidad(n, A)){
           n_nodos++;
         }
         cuenta_nodos_prof(A.hijoDer(n), p, n_nodos,A);
       }
     }
```

Tras esto simplemente acudimos a una función llamada:

```
     template<class T>
     int nodos_prof(const int& p, const Abin<T>& A){
       int n_nodos = 0;
       cuenta_nodos_prof(A.raiz(), p, n_nodos, A);
       return n_nodos;
     }
```